# Adding in a line chart into my wpf program

Tags: c#, xaml

I need some help here.
I would like to insert line chart into my wpf program using c#.
but however, i dont know how to start.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're asking for...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/LineChartWPF11252009200659PM/LineChartWPF.aspx

welcome to Stack Overflow, but you should really try to google it first ;)